# AngularJs Language Property always as Location Keypair

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I like to always show the language property in the address-bar. `$Location.Search("Key", "Value")` do what i like. The Problem is while the user clicks a href the property is gone. Is that possible to always show property and catch a change without changing route ?

```
http://www.address.com/#Start?lang=en-en
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `$routeProvider` `reloadOnSearch` property. This is true by default. Set it to false and if the querystring changes the route would not refresh. See documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)

Something like

`$routeProvider.reloadOnSearch = false;`

during route config stage.

Comment: Do not help. I use href attributes. The property disappear like before.

Comment: How do you define the href. Is it absolute like 'http://..../#' or using url like `/#start?lang-en-en`. The first one would not work.

Comment: no just `/#start` or `/#user` without lang=en-en. Lang=en-en should not change after clicking a href.